# NameError: uninitialized constant ::Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nokogiri

I wrote test for model:

```
describe Video do
  describe 'searching youtube for video existence' do
    it 'should return true if video exists' do
      Video.video_exists?("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgfdlZuVz7I").should be_true
    end
  end  
end
```

Here is model code:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :video_id

  def self.video_exists?(video_url)
    video_url =~ /\?v=(.*?)&/
    xmlfeed = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=#{$1}"))
    if xmlfeed.at_xpath("//openSearch:totalResults").content.to_i == 0
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

But it fails with error:

```
Failures:

  1) Video searching youtube for video existence should return true if video exists
     Failure/Error: Video.video_exists?("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgfdlZuVz7I").should be_true
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Video::Nokogiri
     # ./app/models/video.rb:6:in `video_exists?'
     # ./spec/models/video_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00386 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

I don't know how to solve this, what could be problem?

Comment: Did you do a `require 'nokogiri'` anywhere?

Comment: I thought that it is automatically included, since I added it to Gemfile. Now when I put require 'nokogir' on top of model file, it raises another error: `app/models/video.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   nokogiri`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem was because I didn't add `gem nokogiri` to Gemfile.

After adding it I removed `require 'nokogiri'` and `require 'open-uri'` from model and it works.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're not requiring Nokogiri, so you'll need to do that.

```
uninitialized constant Video::Nokogiri
```

is the give-away. Ruby knows "Nokogiri" is a constant, but doesn't know where to find it.

In your code, Nokogiri relies on Open-URI to retrieve the content so you'll also need to `require 'open-uri'` also. Nokogiri reads the file-handle that Open-URI's `open` returns.

This section could be more concisely written:

```
if xmlfeed.at_xpath("//openSearch:totalResults").content.to_i == 0
  return false
else
  return true
end
```

as:

```
!(xmlfeed.at_xpath("//openSearch:totalResults").content.to_i == 0)
```

or:

```
!(xmlfeed.at("//openSearch:totalResults").content.to_i == 0)
```